# Mongobd/docker-compose: TypeError: Cannot read property 'listDatabases' of undefined in my docker image but not a colleague's image

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, mongo-express

Hi I'm trying to run mongodb to backup some files using docker images (bitnami mongodb:4.0.  and mongo-express). These are specified by this docker-compose file:

```
    version: '3.5'
services:

  mongodb-primary:
    image: 'bitnami/mongodb:4.0'
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-primary
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=primary
      - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME=rs0
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=replicatorkey
      - MONGODB_USERNAME=project
      - MONGODB_PASSWORD=pass
      - MONGODB_DATABASE=project
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./mongo_primary:/bitnami

  mongodb-secondary:
    image: 'bitnami/mongodb:4.0'
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-secondary
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=secondary
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_HOST=mongodb-primary
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME=rs0
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=replicatorkey
      - MONGODB_USERNAME=project
      - MONGODB_PASSWORD=pass
      - MONGODB_DATABASE=project
    depends_on:
      - mongodb-primary
    volumes:
      - ./mongo_secondary:/bitnami

  mongodb-arbiter:
    image: 'bitnami/mongodb:4.0'
    restart: always    
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-arbiter
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=arbiter
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_HOST=mongodb-primary
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME=rs0
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=replicatorkey
    depends_on:
      - mongodb-primary

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always 
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER="mongodb-primary,mongodb-secondary,mongodb-arbiter"
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_DATABASE=project
      - ME_CONFIG_REQUEST_SIZE=1024kb
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=true
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=root
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=root
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_USERNAME=project
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_PASSWORD=pass
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_SITE_GRIDFS_ENABLED=true
    depends_on:
      - mongodb-primary
    ports:
      - 8888:8081
```

This docker-compose file, and the images works on a colleagues work station (kernel:4.15 and Ubuntu 18.04) but on mine (kernel: 5.3.0 Ubuntu 18.04) I get the following error message:

```
Admin database is not accessible
TypeError: Cannot read property 'listDatabases' of undefined
    at Object.connectionData.updateDatabases (/node_modules/mongo-express/lib/db.js:41:11)
    at /node_modules/mongo-express/lib/router.js:94:11
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at param (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
    at param (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
```

Going into the mongo_primary image it seems to be working fine and can connect to the mongo admin database, but it seems mongo-express can't. We've both had a look and are not sure why this is happening. Has anyone else encountered this/fixed it?

Comment: https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express/blame/master/lib/db.js#L54 has a conditional guard, update mongo-express?

Comment: Its the latest version of mongo-express on docker hub (https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo-express). Hopefully a new version will be uploaded soon and I'll see if that helps.